# How Would You Make A Two Column Table With Twig?

Tags: php, twig

I can't for the life of me figure out how to add a `</tr><tr>` every OTHER iteration in a Twig loop.

For instance:

```
$numArray = array(12,13,14,15,16,17,18);
```

Passed to twig, I would loop a table like:

```
<table>
  {% for num in numArray %}
    <tr>
      <td>
        {{num}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

This would output:

```
+-----------+
|    12     |
+-----------+
|    13     |
+-----------+
|    14     |
+-----------+
|    15     |
+-----------+
|    16     |
+-----------+
|    17     |
+-----------+
|    18     |
+-----------+
```

What I'd like to do is get something like this:

```
+-----------+-----------+
|    12     |    13     |
+-----------+-----------+
|    14     |    15     |
+-----------+-----------+
|    16     |    17     |
+-----------+-----------+
|    18     |           |
+-----------+-----------+
```

But I can't for the life of me figure out a way to alternate my row input with anything that doesn't seem hacky.  Honestly I can't even get hacky to work.  Is there a method for this?  Or, should I be looking to write my own extension?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The proper way of doing this is using the **batch** filter. It is new in 1.12.3.

```
<table>
{% for row in numArray|batch(2) %}
  <tr>
  {% for column in row %}
    <td>{{ column }}</td>
  {% endfor %}
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Ref: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/batch.html

Comment: Such an awesome feature!

Answer (score 5):

Something like this would work:

```
<table>
  <tr>
  {% for num in numArray %}
      <td>
        {{num}}
      </td>
  {% if loop.index is even %}
    </tr>
    <tr>
  {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}

  {% if num|length is odd %}
    <td></td>
  {% endif %} 
  </tr>
</table>
```

An alternative way, that feels much less hacky:

```
<table>
  {% for i in range(0, numArray|length-1, 2) %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ numArray[i] }}</td>
    <td>{{ numArray[i+1]|default("") }}</td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you.  I ended up writing an extension so I could get back to some php.  But, this is certainly the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Hi Howard, any change you'd want to open source that extension?

Comment: an update: The batch filter was added in Twig 1.12.3. http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/batch.html

Answer (score 0):

For this specific case you can prepare your array before. So in a loop you will have in each row two variables. Try first example from this site http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html