# Symfony2 Twig table view sort by alphabetical

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a 2 table in database and i want to get the view like this. It is sorted by alphabetical by name. Let's say that I have 2 max rows only and I have 2 data then the 2 data will be display on the left side. If I have 4 data then the other 2 data will display on the right.

> [image]

In my database, the "**Name**" is the parent and the **Account number** and **Bank Name** are the children of the Name. I have created a query in controller something like this:

```
$query = $em->createQuery(
         "SELECT
             e.id, e.name,
             eb.numId, eb.bankName, eb.bankAcct
          FROM Bundle:table1 e
          LEFT JOIN Bundle:table2 eb
          WITH e.id = eb.numId
          ORDER BY e.name ASC"
         );
$entity = $query->getArrayResult();
```

this is my twig:

```
{% for list in entity|batch(1) %}
   <tr>
    {% for column in list %}
        <td>{{ column.entityName }}</td>
        <td>{{ column.bankName }}</td>
        <td class="bank-acct">{{ column.bankAcct }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
   </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I've been trying to work this out and I got stuck. thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441859/how-would-you-make-a-two-column-table-with-twig try this ..

Comment: you can also use foreach loop with [continue](http://ie2.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php) to start from perticular index, so that you can display next rows in different table from previous index of array

Comment: @StrawHat thanks for the link. I have tried the batch(2) but it seems the output was alternating the data. I want the view to be sort by alphabetical from left to right. Anyway, how do I use continue in twig? I'm still new in this framework.

Comment: `continue` is not available in twig,  as per [This](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#adding-a-condition) so you can try using [Slice](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/slice.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is the logic that may work,

## Display First div(which is on left)

```
{% set CurrentIndex = '' %} 
    <div class="1">
    <table>
        {% for i in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]|slice(0, 2) %}
            {# will iterate over 0 and 1 element #}
      <tr>
          {% if loop.index < 2 %}
              #Display table columns

      #set Current index at which loop will break, so that we can use it in next iteration
              {% set CurrentIndex = loop.index %} 
          {% endif %}
      </tr>    
        {% endfor %}

    </table>
    </div>
```

## Display Second div(which is on Right)

```
    <div class="2">
    <table>
        {% for i in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]|slice(CurrentIndex, 2) %}
            {# will iterate over 0 and 1 element #}
      <tr>
          {% if loop.index < 2 %}
              #Display table columns
          {% endif %}
      </tr>    
        {% endfor %}

    </table>
    </div>
```

`loop.index` will give current index and  `slice(start,length)` will display rows from index `start` upto given `length`

I didn't tried this, but logic may work.

Links-
[Slice](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/slice.html) , [set](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/set.html)

Comment: based on the CurrentIndex for the display second div for the Right, this will give an error which is "CurrentIndex" not exist because set CurrentIndex is in another loop but if I set CurrentIndex before the loop for the 2nd div it will cause an error to because of the "loop" that can only be use within the loop.

Comment: @boang3000 edited the answer, declared CurrentIndex outside the loop and it works!!

Comment: it is working but it is not what im looking for :( thanks anyway for the suggestion :)